# How do I define the initial jerk and yank of a cylinder subjected to impact of a rigid body at it's base?

Tags: symmetry, collision, elasticity, continuum-mechanics, jerk

I am trying to solve an axisymmetric longitudinal wave propagation problem during the impact (collision) of a rigid body and the base of a cylinder. On one end the cylinder is rigidly bound to the ground, while the other is subjected to impact pressure. Gravity effects are neglected. Below is a picture of the system.

[image: Impact]

I would like to numerically solve the following equation:

$$ \nabla^4u +k\nabla^2 {\partial^2u \over \partial t^2} + c{\partial^4u \over \partial t^4} =0 \tag 1$$

where $u=u(r,z,t)$ is the longitudinal displacement of the cylinder, $r$ is the radial coordinate, $z$ is the longitudinal coordinate, $t$ is the time coordinate, $\nabla^2$ is the Laplace operator, $\nabla^4$ is the biharmonic operator, and $k$ and $c$ are material constants. This is a special form of Navier's equation derived [here](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.euromechsol.2022.104646).

I have a problem defining all four of the initial conditions of my system. At the initial moment of impact, there is no displacement:

$$u(r,z,0) = 0 \tag 2$$

According to St.Venant's contact theory assumptions, the impact section planar of the cylinder would have the same velocity as the rigid body at the instant when impact starts. It is supposed that the displacement and velocity in the impact contact surface are continuous:

$$ {\partial u(r,0,0) \over \partial t} = v_0 \tag {3a}$$
$$ {\partial u(r,z>0,0) \over \partial t} = 0\tag {3b}$$

In the above condition, $v_0$ is the initial velocity of the rigid body at the moment of contact with the elastic cylinder. Now, using the D'Alembert principle, I wrote down the following boundary condition:

$$ m{\partial ^2 u(r,0,t) \over \partial t^2} = -AE {\partial u(r,0,t) \over \partial z} \tag 4 $$

from which I formulated my third initial condition:

$$ m{\partial ^2 u(r,0,0) \over \partial t^2} = -AE {\partial u(r,0,0) \over \partial z} \tag {5a}$$
$${\partial ^2 u(r,z>0,0) \over \partial t^2 }= 0 \tag {5b}$$

Note that $A$ represents the area of the cylinder's base, while $E$ is the Young's modulus of the cylinder. The mass of the rigid body is denoted by $m$. I got the idea for these initial conditions from [this](https://doi.org/10.4028/www.scientific.net/KEM.693.504) science article.

The problem is, I don't know how to define my fourth initial condition. I need to know the initial [jerk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerk_(physics)) of the cylinder, but I don't know how to derive an expression for it. It should probably be derived from the initial [yank](https://doi.org/10.1242/jeb.180414) (derivative of force with respect to time) between the rigid body and the cylinder. Newton's laws apply to forces, but I am not sure how to extend them to yanks. So my question is, how can I derive the initial jerk of the cylinder?

To summarize, I am trying to solve equation $(1)$, but I don't know the following initial condition:

$$ {\partial^3u (r,z,0)\over \partial t^3} = ? \tag 6$$

Please help me find out how to derive it. Also, a reference to literature where I can look for an answer and read more about this topic would be of help to me.

Comment: This well-formulated question—about how to generally set the third-derivative boundary condition of a vibrations problem in elasticity—is sufficiently broad that it shouldn’t be closed as a homework-type problem. Please consider voting to reopen.

Comment: Thank you for your support. I am not just looking for a formula. I would really like to know the physics behind formulating yank and jerk boundary expressions in impact physics.

Comment: @NikolaRistic It looks like you are talking about boundary conditions, while initial conditions are obvious $u=u_t=u_{tt}=u_{ttt}=0, t=0$.

Comment: An alternative approach to solve my problem would be to take zero initial conditions and use equation $(4)$ as a boundary condition. I would suppose that $u_{tt}$ is measurable and therefore known. It is how I can get the two boundary conditions needed at the upper cylinder's base. However, I would like to know how to define $u_{ttt}$ at $t=0$ by using the Saint-Venant's contact theory assumption for the continuous velocity across the surfaces in contact.

Comment: @NikolaRistic You can use two bc in the bottom side as well $u=u_t=0$.

Comment: I think you mean $u = u_{zz}=0$

Comment: @NikolaRistic It depends on how the lower end is clamped. In what language do you try to implement this model? We can discussed numerical results here or on  https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @AlexTrounev I did the simulations in Matlab. However, I did it using artificial boundary conditions, and not physically consistent ones. That simulation works. Now I would like to do a more realistic simulation for which I need to find the initial condition which is the subject of this post.